# Select option view lag in Angular

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material

I am trying to make a country select dropdown with flag images and country name in it.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Country" ngModel name="nationality [(ngModel)]="nationality">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of Countries" [value]="country.code" >
      <div>
        <img [src]="country.flag" [alt]="country.name">
        <p>{{ country.name }}</p>
      </div>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Now, if I list all the countries of the world the UI gets too laggy. This is definitely due to 200+ flags (definitely svg files). How do I solve this lag?

> Is it Possible to some how show flags for visible options only?

Comment: try virtual scroll, https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: @ABOS, Any Idea how to use it as options of select list?

Answer (score 0):

Try using onPush ChangeDetectionStrategy, which will improve your apps performance by ensuring angular's change detection only happens when a specified action is triggered.

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-country',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    templateUrl: 'country.html'
});

export class CountryComponent {}
```

Read more on: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: How does this impact the give lag ?

Comment: The lag is a performance issue and by default, angular's change detection is triggered from the root App then traverses down to the component then on detecting a change, updates the Dom to be in sync. **OnPush** **ChangeDetectionStrategy** is just one of the optimizations that you can do to improve  the apps performance.

Comment: Here is an article that uses a select with **OnPush** ChangeDetectionStrategy, plus lots more on angular optimization. [Angular Optimization](https://netbasal.com/optimizing-the-performance-of-your-angular-application-f222f1c16354)

Answer (score 0):

As of now, [Virtual scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) fits best in your case.

In fact, there is an ongoing discussion on git at [virtual-scroll inside mat-select new values not visible & big space](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13087). From the same discussion, I found an example on [stackbltiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4xptu-kuu5xg?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.html), that might help you.

Do check the issue discussion on git, as it's not closed yet and it might give your more examples.

Comment: any idea how to put it in select options kind of situations.